# How to code a horizontal line that will extend until it hits a candle (tradin view)

Tags: pine-script

I am attempting to create a script that identifies BoS (break of structures) but cannot figure out how to extend the line to stop when it hits a candle. The image attached is how I want it to look.
Thanks for the help,
Jacob

```
indicator('SMC', overlay=true, max_boxes_count=500, max_lines_count=500)

plotPVT = input.bool(defval=true, title='Plot Pivots', group='Pivots')
pivotLookup  = input.int(defval=1, minval=1, maxval=30,title='Pivot Lookup', group='Pivots', tooltip='Minimum = 1, Maximum = 5')
pvtTopColor = input.color(defval=color.silver, title='Pivot Top Color', group='Pivots', inline='PVT Top Color')
pvtTopTransparency = input.int(defval=0, title='Pivot Top Transparency', minval=0, maxval=100, group='Pivots', inline='PVT Top Color')
pvtBottomColor = input.color(defval=color.silver, title='Pivot Bottom Color', group='Pivots', inline='PVT Bottom Color')
pvtBottomTransparency = input.int(defval=0, title='Pivot Bottom Transparency', minval=0, maxval=100, group='Pivots', inline='PVT Bottom Color')

//////////////////// Pivots //////////////////// 
hih = ta.pivothigh(high, pivotLookup, pivotLookup)
lol = ta.pivotlow(low , pivotLookup, pivotLookup)
top = ta.valuewhen(hih, high[pivotLookup], 0)
bottom = ta.valuewhen(lol, low [pivotLookup], 0)
plot(top, offset=-pivotLookup, linewidth=1, color=(top != top[1] ? na : (plotPVT ? color.new(pvtTopColor, pvtTopTransparency) : na)), title="Pivot Top")
plot(bottom, offset=-pivotLookup, linewidth=1, color=(bottom != bottom[1] ? na : (plotPVT ? color.new(pvtBottomColor, pvtBottomTransparency) : na)), title="Pivot Bottom")
```

Comment: What should happen when there is a new pivot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: no image attached.

Comment: There is no concept of `candle` as a drawn structure on the screen. As candles can be Renko or a single line, you cannot define collision of objects (your line and the candle)? Lines always run at a price level on the chart. Why not stop displaying the line when a candle at the same position exceeds a certain price level?